# ImageView swap images with same button

Tags: java, android

I made a screen to add location, I placed a navigationView with two buttons a gallery and another to take pictures, I want to know what I do so that the button put the image in each imageview according to click, for example if I click the imageView1 open the navigationView with the two buttons I choose the image, when I click on the imageView2 I choose another image and so on

```
//click to display navigationView with setVisible
 final ImageView imageAdicionar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_adicionar);
        imageAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                navigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                navigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }enter code here
        });

//click to display navigationView with setVisible
magem =(ImageView) findViewById(enter code hereR.id.ivImage);

        imagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

            {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View v){

                 NavigationView  navigationView1= (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_foto);

                 navigationView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    navigationView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);








//button to call gallery method


        final ImageView foto2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_navgaleria);
        foto2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, GALERIA_IMAGE);
                navigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                navigationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);




//gallery method

   @Override
        protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == GALERIA_IMAGE) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));




                imagem.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);


            }



//button to call photo method

  if (requestCode == TIRAR_FOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                foto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

make both of the view (ImageView and Button visible) overlap each other with same size and width, and after selecting image to ImageView, run the below mention line,

```
imageButton.alpha = 0f
```

the above code will make the button disappear by changing the opacity of button to 0.

Comment: I think you do not understand I think, I do not want to overlay the image that I create a loop that changes the image from the button that is in the navigationView can you help me with it?